# stl list passed by reference to a function is not letting to be modified by the reference

Tags: c++, list, stl, pass-by-reference

I'm quite new to stl's. Could someone let me know what is happening here ?
why would the below code seg fault at `l.erase(i);` . I hope to see the modified list `l` in main since i pass the list by reference. What is wrong here ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void erase (list<int> &l,int v){
    list<int>::iterator i=l.begin();
    for(;i!=l.end();++i){
        if(*i==v)
            l.erase(i);
    }
}

int main()
{
    list <int> a;
    a.push_back(4);
    a.push_back(5);
    a.push_back(6);
    list<int>::iterator i=a.begin();
    for(;i!=a.end();++i) cout << *i << " ";
    erase(a,5);
    cout << "\nafter:\n";
    list<int>::iterator j=a.begin();
    for(;j!=a.end();++j) cout << *j << " ";
}
```

Comment: Instead of the loop you could just use the [`std::list::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove) member function. `l.remove(v);` will erase all elements with that value.

Comment: Thank you Blastfurnace, i found out from the link why wouldn't the erase work here and yes i knew we could use remove , but was keen on knowing why not erase. Thanks anyway.